# How to wait for Firebase Task to complete to get result as an await function

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Real Time Database from Firebase on java for Android and I am trying to write a set of helper function to facilitate read and write functions from/to the RTDB.

My function looks like the following and is supposed to return a HashMap of my Parking objects on the database; I get a reference to my database and add an `onSuccessListener` where I iterate through the snapshot and add each `Parking` object to my HashMap and return the HashMap `parkings`.

The problem is the function returns `parkings` with no values in it before the onSuccessListener runs.

```
public static ArrayList<Parking> getParkingLots() {
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Task<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotTask = mDatabase.get();
    ArrayList<Parking> parkings = new ArrayList<Parking>();
    dataSnapshotTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> parkingsData = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot parking :
                    parkingsData) {
                parkings.add(parking.getValue(Parking.class));
            }
        }
    });
    return parkings;
}
```

I tried this implementation as well where I directly try and get the results from the Task `datSnapshotTask` but I get an exeption thrown
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete`.

```
   public static HashMap<String, Parking> getParkingLots() {
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Task<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotTask = mDatabase.get();
    Iterable<DataSnapshot> parkingsData = dataSnapshotTask.getResult().getChildren();
    HashMap<String, Parking> parkings = new HashMap<String, Parking>();
    for (DataSnapshot parking :
            parkingsData) {
        parkings.put(parking.getKey(), parking.getValue(Parking.class));
    }

    return parkings;
}
```

Is there a way to get the results from the Task in an await fashion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, since it may have to come from the server. While the data is being loaded, your main code continues to run. Then when the data is available, the task completes and your `onSuccess` gets called.

It's easiest to see what this means in practice by running in a debugger, or by adding some logging:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Log.i("Firebase", "1. Starting to load data");
Task<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotTask = mDatabase.get();
for (DataSnapshot parking: parkingsData) {
    Log.i("Firebase", "2. Got data");
}
Log.i("Firebase", "3. After starting to load data");
```

When you run this code, it prints:

> 1. Starting to load data
> 2. After starting to load data
> 3. Got data

This is probably not the order that you expected, but it actually working as intended. It also explains why you're not getting a result from your `getParkingLots` function: by the time your `return parkings` runs, the `parkings.add(parking.getValue(Parking.class))` hasn't been called yet!

---

The solution for this is always the same: any code that needs the data from the database, needs to be inside your `onSuccess` method or be called from there. This means you **can't return the parking lots** from the function, but you can pass in a callback that takes them as a parameter. Or you could return a `Task<HashMap<String, Parking>>` pretty similar to what Firebase does got `get()`.

For an example of the callback, see my longer explanation on: [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)

Comment: Thank you for that. Could you please tell can we make the next line of code await for execution of the current task, without onSuccessListener?

Comment: There is no way to make asynchronous code behave synchronously. If you check my answer to the question I linked (and more questions I linked from there), you will find various strategies to deal with the asynchronous nature of model cloud API calls.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do in "an await fashion" in **Java**.

But in **Kotlin** we can use [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) for that.

```
suspend fun getParkingLots(): HashMap<String, Parking> {
    val database: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val task: Task<DataSnapshot> = database.get()
    val deferredDataSnapshot: Deferred<DataSnapshot> = task.asDeferred()
    val parkingsData: Iterable<DataSnapshot> = deferredDataSnapshot.await().children // or can use just task.await()
     
    // ... use parkingsData
}
```

Using [`Task.asDeferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/as-deferred.html) extension function we can convert a `Task` into a [`Deferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/) object.
Or can use [`Task.await()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/await.html) without converting the `task` to the `Deferred` object.

To use `Task.asDeferred()` extension function use dependency:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.5.2'
```

To call `suspend` function we need to launch a coroutine

```
someCoroutineScope.launch {
    val parkings = getParkingLots()
}
```

`someCoroutineScope` is a [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) instance. In android it can be [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) in [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) class and [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) in `Activity` or `Fragment`, or some custom `CoroutineScope` instance. Dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. The official documentation of firestore should have a link to this instead of leading people to create a callback-hell for complex cases.